# How to create CNAME record using SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord::createObject

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a CNAME record in softlayer 

`dns_record_create() {
  local rest="https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/createObject.json" # REST API for creating DNS record
  # silence mode. sleep 3 secs and retry one time if a transient error is returned
  curl -g --retry 1 --retry-delay 3 --user "${auth}" -X POST -d '{"parameters":[{"domainId":"'${zone_id}'","host":"'${newhost}'","type":"'${record_type}'","data":"'${oldhost}'","ttl":"'900'"}]}' "${rest}" 
}`

`oldhost="prod-staging-txndr-flex"
newhost="prod-staging-txndr-flex-ros"`

i get back a response, but when i do nslookup on the alias it doesn't return  anything

how to create a CNAME resource to an existing hostname in dns

Comment: The json structure you are using seems to be correct, maybe reading this you can figure out the problem http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/articles/dns-overview-resource-records

Comment: Here some examples about DNS https://softlayer.github.io/tags/dns/